# gd - imagecopyresampled: strange lines of code

Tags: php, gd

I have a form in which there's an input type file whom name is 'foto'

The goal is to resize the foto that the user is uploading before going into the database.

The main error is that when i click on submit the page shows me tons of strange code like this:

```
����JFIF��m���b~bs�I$��'$V�ڳ�v,HL���rr0{ �r�I4����nCT�����O���%�vw|��;��[쯧��!VOݓI&Ҽ�M춶��o�Z�ѥ��Vb���������� ۧ��b��zi8Pr�%�9 ��猞3!�Dx�,U�8t�F�cМ�X��lP�
```

If i click on submit i do the following instructions

```
$fFoto="";

if($_FILES['foto']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

     $fFile="/upload/inserzionisti/".$id."_".$_FILES["foto"]["name"];
     $fFoto=$id."_".$_FILES["foto"]["name"];

     $percent = 0.5;

     list($width,$height) = getimagesize("upload/inserzionisti/".$fFoto."");
     $new_width = $width * $percent;
     $new_height = $height * $percent;

     $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
     $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("upload/inserzionisti/".$fFoto."");

        imagecopyresampled($image_p,$image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$width,$height);
     imagejpeg($image_p,null,100);

     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"],".".$fFile);
     $sql = "UPDATE inserzionisti SET FotoUrl ='$fFoto' where Id=$id";
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `imagejpeg` with a null second parameter just outputs the image to the browser. That's what you're seeing.

Comment: Add `header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");` before `imagejpeg($image_p,null,100)` and you'll see the image. Or change the second parameter of `imagejpeg()` to save the file somewhere.

Comment: Indeed. That "strange code" is actually the image itself, just in the wrong format ;) The clue is the letters "JFIF", which is the file identifier of the header of the [JPEG File Interchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) file that's being output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$fFoto="";

if($_FILES['foto']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  $fFile="/upload/inserzionisti/".$id."_".$_FILES["foto"]["name"];
  $fFoto=$id."_".$_FILES["foto"]["name"];

  $percent = 0.5;

  list($width,$height) = getimagesize("upload/inserzionisti/".$fFoto."");
  $new_width = $width * $percent;
  $new_height = $height * $percent;

  $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
  // create the new image from the uploaded file
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"]);

  imagecopyresampled($image_p,$image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$width,$height);
  // add the new path as second parameter of imagejpeg() to save the file in the specified location
  imagejpeg($image_p,$fFile,100); 

  // the following line isn't necessary anymore
  // move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"],".".$fFile);
  $sql = "UPDATE inserzionisti SET FotoUrl ='$fFoto' where Id=$id";
```

Comment: Reeno, it's me again. The new path is the folder or the folder + the foto? in any case, no errors but no save...thanks

Comment: Ah, sorry, I think I mixed up the variables. imagejpeg() needs the new folder+file name, which I think is $fFile in your example. I edited the code.